# Uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have no idea why my program is crashing. I know roughly where it is crashing and that is about it. The code is below, and is supposed to add a clear sprite (1×480 px) and remove an enemy that it hits, if any. The code is:

```
-(void)gunManAttack:(ccTime)dt {
    int avalibleSpace = 210;
    int minY = gunShot.contentSize.height/2;
    int maxY = avalibleSpace - gunShot.contentSize.height/2;
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

    int aOa;
    BOOL allowAttackGun = YES;

    NSMutableArray *enemiesToKill = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    gunShot.position = ccp((gunShot.contentSize.width/2), actualY);
    [self addChild:gunShot];

    CGRect gunShotRect = CGRectMake(
                               gunShot.position.x - (gunShot.contentSize.width/2), 
                               gunShot.position.y - (gunShot.contentSize.height/2), 
                               gunShot.contentSize.width, 
                               gunShot.contentSize.height
                               );

    for (CCSprite *enemy in allEnemies)
    {
        CGRect enemyARect = CGRectMake(
            enemy.position.x - (enemy.contentSize.width/2),
            enemy.position.y - (enemy.contentSize.height/2),
            enemy.contentSize.width, 
            enemy.contentSize.height
        );

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(gunShotRect, enemyARect) && allowAttackGun == YES)
        {
            [enemiesToKill addObject:enemy]; //Add to enemiesToKill array (clean up array [enemies])
            money = money + 100; //Add money for the kill
            [moneyL setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %i", money]]; //Update the money on the screen
            aOa = 1; //Tell the aOa, the enemy was in the walking array
            allowAttackGun = NO; //Prevent mutliple enemies from being killed (telling the program the attack has been completed)
        }
    }

    for (CCSprite *enemy in attackingEnemies)
    {
        CGRect enemyARect = CGRectMake(
            enemy.position.x - (enemy.contentSize.width/2),
            enemy.position.y - (enemy.contentSize.height/2),
            enemy.contentSize.width,
            enemy.contentSize.height
        );

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(gunShotRect, enemyARect) && allowAttackGun == YES)
        {
            [enemiesToKill addObject:enemy]; //Add to enemiesToKill array (clean up array [enemies])
            money = money + 100; //Add money for the kill
            [moneyL setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %i", money]]; //Update the money on the screen
            aOa = 2; //Tell the aOa, the enemy was in the walking array
            allowAttackGun = NO; //Prevent mutliple enemies from being killed (telling the program the attack has been completed)
        }
    }

    //Removing enemies from arrays
    for (CCSprite *enemyType1 in enemiesToKill) {
        if (aOa==1) { //If the aOa is 1 (aka the enemy is in the walking array)
            [allEnemies removeObject:enemyType1]; //Remove the enemy from the allEnemies (walking) array
        }
        if (aOa==2) { //If the aOa is 2 (aka the enemy is in the attacking array)
            [attackingEnemies removeObject:enemyType1]; //Remove the enemy from the attackingEnemies (attacking) array
        }
        [self removeChild:enemyType1 cleanup:YES]; //Then remove the element from this array (due to the fact it has alredy been removed from the other arrays)
    }
    [enemiesToKill release];
    [self removeChild:gunShot cleanup:YES];
}
```

The debugger outputs this:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString contentSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80b7450' ***
```

How can I find out where it's crashing?

Comment: Did you try to debug step by step using XCode debugger? It might help you find the line code that provoke the apps crash

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to pin-point the line throwing the exception: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: The exception says that [__NSCFString contentSize] is unrecognised.  So you're calling contentSize on something you shouldn't be.  In your code above you call it on two different objects.  One is enemy and the other is gunShot.  enemy looks pretty well defined as a CCSprite, but I can't see a definition for gunShot.  Where has it been defined?  If it's neither of these two then maybe you have a bug outside this method.

Comment: I define gunShot in my init:
    gunShot = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"gunShot.png"];

and I found the two lines it doesn't like
    int minY = gunShot.contentSize.height/2;
    gunShot.position = ccp((gunShot.contentSize.width/2), 10);

Comment: well i fixed it, by moving the where i define gunShot, into this function, but i have no idea why that fixed it. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: @user1091516 My answer explain that. You load your sprite, but you don't notify the memory management system that you want to keep it for further use (`retain`).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're missing a `retain` somewhere, so an object you're trying to use gets deallocated, its memory reused, and you try to send a message (`contentSize`) to something that is now a `NSString`.

Most likely candidate here: `gunShot`.

You should try to enable NSZombies by the way, it should help with debugging.